# Changing to another PHP file's included HTML via form

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP file that looks somewhat like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XML Converter</title>
</head>

<body>  
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1 for="file">Choose your .zip file:</h1> <br />
            <input class="btn" type="file" name="file"/>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The `<form action="upload.php">` line references another PHP file that is in this form:

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
....
</html>
```

How do I make the `action=""` such that the webpage displays the second PHP file's (`upload.php`) HTML?

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question, do you want to submit form on same page and display `upload.php` html in first php file ?

Comment: Page 1 doesn't display the contents of the `action` attribute. It sends the user to that page and whatever is there is executed.

Comment: What exactly is happening now, and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I'm trying to submit on the first page and have the second page displayed. To Patrick's question: the first page is displayed while upload.php runs. I would like for the second page to be displayed while upload.php runs.

Comment: @BenGardner You should you `if(isset($_FILES['file'])` if its true then show code of upload.php else default form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the contents from "upload.php" on the same page where the form located after submitting the form, All you need to do is use AJAX. Using the AJAX method, You can get content from the upload.php page and display the content without refreshing the browser

Comment: Thanks, I used AJAX and the onclick method to reload the document from a .txt as in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)